# The existence of $2^{\aleph_1}$ stationary subsets of $\omega_1$ such that the intersection of any two is at most countable under Principle Diamond.

Tags: set-theory

Chapter 12 of Jech & Hrbacek's "Introduction to Set Theory" asks the following as exercise 5.4:

> Assuming $\diamondsuit$ show that there exists $2^{\aleph_1}$ stationary subsets of $\omega_1$ such that the intersection of any two is at most countable.
>
> [*Hint*: Consider $S_X = \{ \alpha < \omega_1 \space|\space X \cap \alpha \in W_\alpha\}$ for all $X \subset \omega_1$.]

$\diamondsuit$ is Principle Diamond, for which I believe the book uses a weaker version than that used by other books I looked up, hence I quote from page 234:

> **Principle $\diamondsuit$** $\quad$ There exists a sequence $\langle W_\alpha \space | \space \alpha < \omega_1\rangle$ such that, for each $\alpha < \omega_1$, $W_\alpha \subset P(\alpha)$, $W_\alpha$ is at most countable, and for any $X\subset \omega_1$ the set $\{\alpha < \omega_1 \space | \space X \cap \alpha \in W_\alpha\}$ is stationary.

Usually the exercises from this book are easy, and most of the time the hints give out almost the entire answer. That is why I suspect the answer to be a subset of the set $S$ that contains all the sets of the form that the hint suggests. But, my problems are:

1) Given $X\subset\omega_1$, how can I choose a $Y\subset\omega_1$ such that the intersection of $S_X \cap S_Y$ is at most countable?

2) It is easy, given $X\subset\omega_1$, to choose $Y\subset\omega_1$ such that $S_X \neq S_Y$. I can even go further and construct a countable subset of $S$, but I cannot seem to construct or find one of size $2^{\aleph_1}$. How can I guarantee a subset of that size?

Comment: You don't *choose* $Y$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is that a hint or are you pointing out a mistake in my choice of word? :)

Comment: I point out your mistake. Not in the choice of words, but in the concept of what you're supposed to do in the exercise.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I cannot think of two stationary sets S_X and S_Y whose intersection is at most countable. And I feel like if I was able to do that, I might be able to do what the exercise asks.

Comment: The exercise essentially suggests that *if* $X\neq Y$, then $S_X\cap S_Y$ can only be countable. You don't need to "think about two stationary sets". You need to prove that it doesn't matter which two you took, as long as they are of this form, they will only have a countable intersection.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That is my point! I do not see how that is true.

Comment: Start by considering the case where $W_\alpha$ is a singleton (the standard formulation of diamond).

Comment: @AsafKaragila That case is easy. But, when each $W_\alpha$ has at least two elements, what keeps $S_X\cap S_Y$ from being uncountable for $X\neq Y$? We might, for instance, have $X=\omega$ and $Y=\omega + 1$, and see that whenever $X\cap \alpha \in W_\alpha$, then $Y\cap \alpha \in W_\alpha$ as well.

Comment: Well, you need to use the fact that *every* $A\subseteq\omega_1$ is guessed on stationarily many points. That *is* the technical point.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I spent time thinking about what you said, but, instead of finding a reason why $S_X \cap S_Y$ is at most countable for $X \neq Y$, I ended up finding a reason why it might not be so. For some fixed $X$ and $Y$, consider Diamond under $\langle U_\alpha \rangle$, which is the same as $\langle W_\alpha \rangle$ except possibly at $\alpha \in S_X$, where $U_\alpha = W_\alpha \cup \{Y\cap \alpha\}$. Surely $\langle U_\alpha \rangle$ is a sequence of Diamond properties, but we also have $S_X \cap S_Y = S_X$ (uncountable) for this sequence.